# Cookie token sending to server via header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, backend

This is my first attempt to dealing with server

**Using React and express**

Saving token to browser cookie from server

```
//After login request
res.cookie('token', token, {maxAge: 3600000} ).json({ user: userDoc, message: 'message!', status: 200 });
```

**Question is here**

How can I send token value from client along with each API request for further app process?

After research I found two options!.

**Option A**

```
//Collecting data from cookie 
    let token = Cookies.get('token');
    axios.get("/api/, { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`} });
```

**Option B**

Here is my confusion that I have read ,that browser send cookie along with each api automatically without manually adding in  **header**

I have tested in server `let { cookies } = req;` and its working

**Question**

Which option is the correct way ?

If yes A or B - why? and why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering Option B is relying on server for dealing with cookies.

When dealing with sensitive data such as authorisation tokens, you must choose option B.

This is because the client side scripting should not get access to the sensitive data by any means.

To prevent client from accessing the cookie, use HttpOnly flag in your call to res.cookie.

HttpOnly cookies cannot be accessed by client side scripting. So it is pretty safe to use.

Even if data is not sensitive, you should go with option B. Since your browser is automatically sending the cookie payload, you don't have to deal with it manually.

Comment: I have typed this answer from Mobile so couldn't include any code samples or references.

Comment: , I have been using cookie token for user logged in or out checking purpose - especially for page changing in react

Comment: Okay. Generally people use cookies in combination with local storage to create more fool proof solutions. Authentication in itself is a very complex subject. I always recommend a third party provider like authO for production grade applications. If you are learning, it is okay to try few things out and understand how auth works.